# org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-bin.zip'

Tags: java, elasticsearch, grails, gradle

I have an grails project, I am getting 
"***java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-bin.zip***'." error.

I have used 
grails 3.3.6,
gradle 3.1,
jdk 1.8.

I am getting this error while implementing elastic search on it.
I got this error after added this dependency "***runtime 'org.elasticsearch.plugin:mapper-attachments:2.4.6'***" in build.gradle.
And I am using elasticsearch grails plugin is 2.4.0.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked other related posts, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47063484/cant-get-elasticsearch-plugin-to-work-with-grails-3 ?